# Set which is locally $\iota-$null but not $\iota$-null

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, product-space

I've been working on this problem for a while but cannot seem to reach a solution. Let $\iota(A)= \bar{\bar{I}}(\xi_A)$ where $\xi_A$ is the characteristic function of the set $A=\{(x,0) | x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ seen as a subset of the set $\mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{R}_d$ is the set of real numbers with the discrete topology and $\mathbb{R}$ the set of real numbers with the usual topology. Now $\bar{\bar{I}}$ is given by,

$$\bar{\bar{I}}(g) = inf\{\bar{f} | f \text{ is lower semicontinuous}, f \geq g\}.$$

Now, for $g$ a positive lower semicontinuous function,

$$\bar{I}(g) = sup\{I(f)| f \in C_{00}^+(\mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R}) , f \leq g\},$$

taking the set $C_{00}^+(\mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R})$ as the set of functions with compact support from $\mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and $I$ a nonnegative linear functional defined on $C_{00}^+(\mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R})$, namely the Radon Measure.

I need to prove that $\iota(A)\neq 0$, however for every compact set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R}$ we have that $\iota(A \cap K)=0$.

My attempt to the solution is noticing that a compact set $K$ in $\mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R}$ can be seen as $K = \{x_1,...,x_n\} \times K'$ where $K' \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a compact set. Therefore, if one of the $x_i$ for $i=1,...,n$ is not 0, then $\iota(A \cap K)=\iota(\emptyset) = 0$. However, if one of the $x_i$ is 0 then $A \cap K = \{0\} \times K '$ and I don't know how to prove that $\iota(\{0\} \times K ')=0$, much less argue that $\iota(A) \neq 0$. Any thoughts on this would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: So this is what it has to do with measure theory! I already accidentally retagged.

Comment: @RomandadeGore Can you recall the definition of the Radon measure on $C_{00}^+(\mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your general form of a compact set of $\mathbb R_d \times \mathbb R$ is not quite right: The correct form would be $\{x_1\} \times K_1 \cup \cdots \cup \{x_n\} \times K_n$ where $K_1, \ldots, K_n$ are compact in $\mathbb R$. Indeed, any such set is clearly compact since finite products and unions of compact sets are compact, and if $K \subset \mathbb R_d \times \mathbb R$ is a compact set, then since the projections are continuous and continuous images of compact sets are compact, $\pi_{\mathbb R_d}(K) = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ for certain elements $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb R$, and for each $j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, the set
$$
K_j := \{y \in \mathbb R| (x_j,y) \in K\}
$$
is compact as a closed subset of a compact set; indeed, it is a closed subset of $\pi_{\mathbb R}(K)$, because vertical open sets are open, since the horizontal space carries the discrete topology.

Now note the following: Suppose that $g$ is already lower semi-continuous. Then
$$
\overline I(g) = g,
$$
because one obviously can't do any better than $g$ itself. Thus, we obtain
$$
\overline{\overline I}(g) = \inf \{f| f \text{ lower semi-continuous}, f \ge g\}.
$$
From this we see that whenever $K \cap A \neq \emptyset$ (be $K$ compact or not), then in fact $\iota(A \cap K) \neq 0$ because if $(x,0) \in A \cap K$, then
$$
\overline{\overline I}(g)(x,0) \ge 1.
$$
Thus, the proposition as stated is false.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification on the compact sets, it was very helpful! However, your answer made me realize I was taking the wrong definition of $\bar{I}$. I've edited the question. Does it change at all?

Comment: This comes from "Real and Abstract Analysis" by Hewitt & Stromberg, the proposition is not false at all, in fact it can be proved easily that $i(A\cap F)=0$ when $F$ is compact, but I'm not sure as to how it can be proved that $i(A)>0$ (I suspect $i(A)=\infty$). What do you even mean by $\overline{\overline I}(g)(x,0) \ge 1$ ?

Comment: @RomandadeGore, See Bourbaki, Integration, ch. 5 re upper integral ($\iota(A)$) vs. essential integral ($\iota^\bullet(A) = \sup \iota(A\cap K)$ where supremum is taken over all compact subsets). $\iota(A) \neq \iota(A\cap K) < \infty$ implies $\iota(A)=\infty.$ Hint: use definition of lower semi-continuous function to prove that $\bar{I}(g) = \infty$ for  any $g \ge \xi_A.$